# How to create dropdown list that offers cities with its first letters

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am creating a geographical application: I have two editText fields for "From" and "To" points. I want to make it so, that when first letters are added to the editText, dropdown list appears suggesting cities, countries, etc.
For example if I write "new" - New York, New Jersey, New Orleans appears.
So, I want the same, as realised in Google Mapps app.

Sorry if not clear, I am new to android, even have no idea how to name this.

Comment: Use AutoCompleteTextView . Check this - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

Comment: This question would be better served if you could add some more information about what you have tried.  You may be better served overall by searching on Google for related solutions and playing with them before coming here with questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can not use the AutoCompleteTextView tag in your xml in the EditText and passing it an array of the possible completions

```
//Create Array Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, languages);
//Find TextView control AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.languages);
//Set the number of characters the user must type before the drop down list is shown
acTextView.setThreshold(1);
//Set the adapter acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: //Create Array Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, languages);
                //Find TextView control
        AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.languages);
        //Set the number of characters the user must type before the drop down list is shown
                acTextView.setThreshold(1);
                //Set the adapter
        acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Please move your code from a comment into your answer. With formatting. Thanks